# OS can not see 1G LAN and 2.5G LAN on new motherboard

Tags: motherboard, ethernet, lan

I just buy a new motherboard [MAG B550 TOMAHAWK](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MAG-B550-TOMAHAWK/Specification), and when I plug in an ethernet cable to my one of this port  Realtek® RTL8125B 2.5G LAN or  1x Realtek® RTL8111H 1G LAN. It will not light up and the internet doesn't work. I installed new drivers from the official page and later directly from Realtek but I always get the same response from driver installer

> Realtek ethernet controller driver was not found if deep sleep mode

I read I should return that MB back to shop and take new? is possible that the LAN component is broken?

Comment: So you are saying that neither one of your ethernet ports work? It's more likely that there's a cable issue or an issue at the other end at the router/switch than an issue with both ports.

Answer (score 0):

I updated BIOS and all work fine now ...